# Backend in node.js used for OpenAI image generation giving error code of 400

Tags: node.js, backend, openai-api

I am  building  a backend using Node.js for OpenAI API image generation. This is what I need: `Generate image based on prompt`  I keep getting an error (400) from OpenAI . The generation is not working. I have configured OpenAI api key and mongoDB_URL in a `.env` file. But I'm not sure what is wrong.

`Node.js:`

```
import express from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from 'openai';



dotenv.config();

const router=express.Router();

const configuration= new Configuration({
    apiKey:process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai= new OpenAIApi(configuration);

router.route('/').get((req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello everyone !!')
})

router.route('/').post(async(req,res)=>{
    try {
       //came from frontend
        const {prompt}=req.body;

        const aiResponse=await openai.createImage({
            prompt,
            n:1,
            size:'1024x1024',
            response_format:'b64_json',
        });

        const image=aiResponse.data.data[0].b64_json;
        res.status(200).json({photo:image});
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send(error?.response.data.error.message || 'Something went wrong..')
        
    }
})


export default router;
```

`Request from React app:`

```
  const [formFill,setFormFill]=useState({
    name:'',
    prompt:'',
    photo:''
  })

  const [imgGenerate,setImgGenerate]=useState(false);
  const imgCreate= async ()=>{
    if (formFill.prompt) {
      try {
        setImgGenerate(true);
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/dalleApi', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            prompt: formFill.prompt,
          }),
        });

        const data = await response.json();
        setFormFill({ ...formFill, photo: `data:image/jpeg;base64,${data.photo}` });
      } catch (err) {
        alert(err);
      } finally {
        setImgGenerate(false);
      }
    } else {
      alert('Please provide a proper prompt !');
    }

  }
```

`Error response:`

```
Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (D:\Web dev Projects\ai_image_generation_app\backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (D:\Web dev Projects\ai_image_generation_app\backend\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\Web dev Projects\ai_image_generation_app\backend\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:322:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'User-Agent': 'OpenAI/NodeJS/3.3.0',
      Authorization: 'Bearer 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',
      'Content-Length': 55
    },
    method: 'post',
    data: '{"n":1,"size":"1024x1024","response_format":"b64_json"}',
    url: 'https://api.openai.com/v1/images/generations'
  },
```

I have tried the code provided in `Node.js` and `Request from react app`, but I am unable to figure out the problem. Please help me out.

Comment: You should delete the API Key ASAP

Comment: @loremipsum why I should delete API key ? Can you tell me the reasons behind it ?

Comment: Because you posted it on the internet and it is compromised and will likely be abused